# Failed ajax call within wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I previously had help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616577/same-ajax-call-for-multiple-elements) making a generic Ajax function for some checkboxes. I am now trying to integrate that project into a Wordpress site and having a few issues.

Here is my current code:

```
 <label class="rep_label"><input type="checkbox" id="goal1<?php get_current_user_id() ?>" name="GOAL_1_HIT" value="1" <?php if($rep_goal1_hit == 'YES'){echo "checked";}?> />
            <?php echo $rep_goal1; ?></label>
<br />          
<label class="rep_label"><input type="checkbox" id="goal2<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>" name="GOAL_2_HIT" value="1" <?php if($rep_goal2_hit == 'YES'){echo "checked";}?> />
            <?php echo $rep_goal2; ?></label>
<br />          
<label class="rep_label"><input type="checkbox" id="goal3<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>" name="GOAL_3_HIT" value="1" <?php if($rep_goal3_hit == 'YES'){echo "checked";}?> />
            <?php echo $rep_goal3; ?></label>
<br />          
<label class="rep_label"><input type="checkbox" id="incentive<?php echo get_current_user_id() ?>" name="INCENTIVE_HIT" value="1" <?php if($rep_incentive_hit == 'YES'){echo "checked";}?> />
            <?php echo $rep_incentive; ?></label>
```

JS/Ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {  
        var $input = $(this); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'checkbox.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { db_column:$input.attr("name"), strState:$input.is(":checked"), user:"<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" },
            success: function() { // this happens after we get results
                $input.attr('checked', true);               
            },
            error:function(){
                $input.attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP

```
<?php

$db_column = $_POST['db_column'];
$strState = $_POST['strState'];
$user = $_POST['user'];

if(set_cimyFieldValue('$user', '$db_column', '$strState')){
    echo "ok";
} else {
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

I am getting an "unexpected end of input" error on my javascript that I've googled endlessly to no avail.

I had the script within the html and the Ajax call wasn't even being triggered so I moved it to a .js file and included it in the same spot and now the ajax call goes, but returns a 404 on the php file.

This is only the tip of the iceberg of Ajax I'm going to have to implement. What general considerations do I need to be aware of using my own Ajax functions within Wordpress?

If anyone is familiar with Cimy Extra User Fields, I am merely trying to make an ajax driven front end for the fields provided from that plugin.  I think I have problem trying to use a plugin function in my php file...

Comment: After more digging, I realize what I'm really looking for is just general usage of ajax to call a php function. I think much of what I've done above is excessive considering the plugin I'm using.

Answer (score -1):

```
data: ({ db_column:$input.attr("name"), strState:$input.is(":checked"), user:"<?php echo $current_user->ID; ?>" })
```